# .NET 4 breaking W3C rules

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, sitefinity-4

Hopefully a simple one.

I have a .NET 4 website built in Sitefinity. The HTML that is rendered is creating the following hidden field and script:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ctl04" id="ctl04" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.setServerId("ctl04", "ctl00$ctl04");
Sys.Application._enableHistoryInScriptManager();
//]]>
</script>
```

The problem with this is it is breaking W3C strict guidelines, with the message:

line 75 column 52 - Error: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "p", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "div", "pre", "address", "fieldset", "ins", "del" start-tag

Any idea how I can make this right?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was a Sitefinity 4 thing.....all fixed now.